# Invalidating again and again Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I am using this code to draw some circles but it keeps redrawing and redrawing and stops with error that textBox1.text has bad number format even when I try 5 or 6. What is wrong with this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace terc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
            //
        }






        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(KresliTerc);
        }

        protected void KresliTerc(object sender,PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics grfx = e.Graphics;
            int pocet = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            label1.Text = pocet.ToString();

            for(int i=1; i <= pocet; i++)
            {
                grfx.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black,ClientSize.Width/2,ClientSize.Height/2,50*i,50*i);
                Invalidate();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the problem with the number format. Can you expand on that a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(KresliTerc);
```

where are you calling this , since it is a paint event it will call again and again when painting occurs

Comment: Also, you should add the handler method *multiple* times. Each time the button is clicked, you'll add a new handler, and *each* of them will be called.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you attach the event handler each time that the button is clicked? This means that you will have as many event handlers as button clicks, which is I doubt is what you want.

However, your repaint problem is probably the fact that you call `Invalidate` inside the Paint event handler. This will force a new repaint of the form. So for each time that you paint, you will trigger a new paint, which will trigger a new paint and so on.

Comment: You only need to Invalidate once from OUTSIDE the Paint event

Comment: override the OnPaint event, then do you custom drawing!

Comment: But I need to draw when someone clicks the Button

Comment: @Dunemaster: then you should call `Invalidate` in the button click handler, and move the code to attach the paint event handler into the `MainForm` constructor (after the call to `InitializeComponent`).

Answer (score 1):

You should not invalidate in a Paint call.

Handle the painting based on some integer or boolean values.
Set the integer or boolean values in click events and just call Invalidate in the button click handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
       Boolean isButtonClicked;

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.isButtonClicked)
            {
                this.isButtonClicked = false;
                // some paint logic goes down here...
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.YellowGreen, 12, 12, 54, 54);
            }
        }

        private void HandleOnButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.isButtonClicked = true;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
```